# Finding critical points of $f(x,y)= \sin x+\sin y + \cos(x+y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the critical points of function$$
> f(x,y)=\sin x + \sin y + \cos(x+y),$$
>   where $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $0<y<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

What I have done:
$$f_{x}=\cos(x)-\sin(x+y),\\
f_{y}=\cos(y)-\sin(x+y).$$

From $f_{x}=0$, $\cos(x)=\sin(x+y)$. From $f_{x}=0$, $\cos(y)=\sin(x+y)$. I do not know where to go from here.

My attemps:
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\sin(x+y)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right).$$

Comment: I'm confused how to find critical points of trigonometric function

Comment: Remember that to get "$\sin x$" you need to type "\$ \sin x \$"!  Cheers!

Comment: @Dzoooks I get $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ and set it to 0, but how to find the x and y

Comment: @Dzoooks sorry, I has edited it

Answer (score 3):

$$f_x = \cos x - \sin(x+y) = 0\\
f_y = \cos y - \sin(x+y) = 0$$
Subtracting one from the other we get $\cos x = \cos y$ and with the restrictions of $x,y$ to $(0,\frac {\pi}{2})$ we can say $x= y$ and $\cos x - \sin 2x = 0$

$$\cos x(1-\sin x) = 0\\x = \frac {\pi}{6}$$

$\frac {\pi}{2}$ would also solve the equation but the domain says strictly less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: thanks, I also got the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\cos x - \sin(x+y) = 0$$

$$\frac{df}{dy}=\cos y - \sin(x+y) = 0$$

Exploding the $\sin$s

$$\cos x - \sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y = 0$$

$$\cos y - \sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y = 0$$

Dividing the first with $\cos x$, the second with $\cos y$:

$$1 - \tan x \cos y - \sin y = 0$$

$$1 - \sin x - \cos x \tan y = 0$$

Expressing $\tan x$ from the first:

$$\tan x = \frac{1- \sin y}{\cos y}$$

...and now substitute it into the second equation. You have to express $\sin x$ with $\tan x$, there is a trigonometrical identity for that, but unfortunately this small margin is too narrow here to contain. ;-)

But the result will be a second degree equation and you will simply solve it.

Comment: can't you just do $\sin(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)=\sin(x+y)$?

Comment: @peterh This is not a hint. In fact it is the solution.

Comment: @JackSparrow Why would it be true? It looks to me non-sense (if you don't have some special circumstance).

Comment: @tienlee He still has to dig out the identity to express sinus in the term of tangent, then solve the resulting equation, and substitute the result back into the original equation. This is actually bigger work as here I gave. Thus, here I only shown the direction.

Comment: @peterh there's no way it will take that long, it's supposed to be exam problem which takes 5-6 mins each question.

Comment: @JackSparrow It is right, the other answer is better. Btw, the intention of the site is not to solve exam problems.

Comment: Shouldn’t the second equation be: $1-sin(x)-cos(x)tan(y) = 0$ -after dividing by cos(y)?

Comment: @elson1608 Thanks, I fixed it :-)